# wcf exception when the dataload increases

Tags: wcf, exception

iam working in an silverlight application witha datgrid displaying the records as per the value of a text box

when the records exceeds 3000 it displays an error as below and it works fine when the rcord count is below 3000  ? how to overcome this exception or to handle this

```
        base    {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)}  System.SystemException {System.Net.WebException}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably hitting the MaxReceivedMessageSize or MaxItemsInObjectGraph limits defined respectively in the binding and the behavior.

You need to update both configurations with these parameters set to a sufficiently high value (Int32.MaxValue)

Comment: MaxReceivedMessageSize: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx

Comment: MaxItemsInObjectGraph: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx